# "Drive Table internal error. Request is too large" as loading data into an app maker deployment

Tags: google-app-maker

I have been working w/ App Maker's Vendor Rating template, and I noticed that every time I attempt to import a non-negligible amount of data into a deployment (like say 1,000 records), I get this error: "Drive Table internal error. Request is too large" I was wondering what this may be due to.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this is related but data import has been broken for several days now for me.